# Simple Symmetric Random Walk on $\mathbb{Z}$ is null recurrent

Tags: stochastic-processes, markov-process, random-walk

**Question:** Consider a simple symmetric random walk on integers, where from every state $i$ you move to states $i-1$ and $ i+1$ with probability half each. Show that this random walk is is *null recurrent*.

*My Approach:*
The random walk is irreducible and there does not exit any stationary distribution, so all states will be null recurrent. But, I tried to show that value of mean recurrence time $\mu_{ii}$ will be infinite. The mean recurrence time is given by:
$$\mu_{ii}= \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}n f_{ii}^{(n)}  $$
Where, $f_{ii}^{(n)}$ is the first return probability to state-$i$.

Since, random walk is irreducible, there will be only one communicating class, so it will be sufficient to show that state-$i$ is null recurrent to prove that the random walk is null recurrent. Now, $$\mu_{ii}= f_{ii}^{(1)}+ 2f_{ii}^{(2)}+3 f_{ii}^{(3)}+ \cdots$$

> I am stuck here. I want to find these values for
> $f_{ii}^{(n)}$ and show that the the series is divergent. Am I right?

Comment: Hi: I didn't read it carefully but I think the answer is here. A heads up that it looks quite involved. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/285377/null-recurrence-of-a-random-walk

Comment: If $f_{ii}^{(n)}$ is the probability of first return to i from i then obviously this is $0$ when $n$ is odd. For $n$ even you can use the Catalan numbers to show $f_{ii}^{(n)}={n-2 \choose  n/2 -1}/(n 2^{n-1})$